# Text Area - When user edit the contents in text area, the text color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have some values in text area, when the user edits the text or add some new texts....those texts alone should be in different color..i am not sure how to implement this..

```
  <textarea rows="50" cols="175" name="textname">
  This is a text area to show some related details regarding the project
  </textarea>
```

When i use this Javascript to change the user editied or entered text to uppercase..

```
 function convert() 
        {
            var str ;
            str = document.getElementById("textname").value;
            document.writeln(str.toUpperCase());
        }
```

This converts all the text to uppercase...can anyone help me out..

Comment: You can't do that with `textarea`, use `div` with `contenteditable` attribute

Comment: is it possible to do with <input type="text"....? type

Comment: You can only provide color to entire text in the `input`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a CSS solution? like:

textarea
{
color: #0faeeb;
text-transform: capitalize
}

Answer (score 0):

You cant do a direct highlighting of the text in the text area and hence you have to use the CSS solution see the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/9Y99F/

`#textarea {
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}`

find the words that have been changed and the construct the HTML according to that so that u can highlight the text that has be changed or modified.

Answer (score 0):

You just use this code in your situation here it is:-

```
 <textarea onclick="this.style.color='red';">something</textarea>
```

Best of luck !